# Already generated ssh key on another machine

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I have generated SSH key on my previous machine (Ubuntu), but now I am moving to another laptop and I want this exact SSH key to take it with me. I have copied **config** **id_rsa** **id_rsa.pub** **known_hosts** files to ~/.ssh folder and try to clone repo from GitLab and error occures:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

Any ideas? On this laptop, user and laptop itself have different usernames.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is picky about permissions of the private key file. Do the following to ensure file permission is correct:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [answers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths) your question.

In ~/.ssh/config, add:

```
# GitLab.com
Host gitlab.com
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_com_rsa
```

Then be sure to do a `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` to make sure everything is working correctly.